# How to get value from VOID type method?

Tags: c#, winforms, composite

At the time of developing the code in c# winforms, i have a problem..

In composite pattern, code is like

//Interface

```
interface Usage
    {  
        public abstract void getinfo();
        public abstract void add(Usage u);
    }
```

//Leaf

```
class status : Usage
    {
        public string strng;
        public status()
        {
            this.strng = "Hello";
        }
        public override void getinfo()
        {

        }
        public override void add(Usage u)
        {
        }
    }
```

//Composite class

```
class composite : Usage
    {
        string strng;
        ArrayList node=new ArrayList();
        public override void add(Usage u)
        {
            node.Add(u);
        }
        public override void getinfo()
        {
            foreach (Usage u in this.node)
            {
                u.getinfo();
            }

        }   
    }
```

But i was unable to capture the string `strng` which is **`Leaf`** (**status**)class? return type of **getinfo()** method is `VOID`.But because of interface method implementation i cannot make it `STRING` return type.
anyone please Resolve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of the getinfo method?

Comment: Whats stopping you to add one more method, make the calls and return a `string`

Comment: ya, actually whenever it calls the getinfo it needs to return local string(strng).and that string to be stored in string variable.

Comment: Actually having `public` or `abstract` modifier in an interface is not a C# compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Robert suggests why not just change it to:

```
interface Usage
{  
    string getinfo();
    void add(Usage u);
}
```

and:

```
class status : Usage
{
    public string strng;
    public status()
    {
        this.strng = "Hello";
    }
    public override string getinfo()
    {
        return strng;
    }
    public override void add(Usage u)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: also make your string "strng" private to encapsulate it properly.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change the interface.  It makes no sense to have a 'get' method be void

Comment: ya thank you but what to write in getinfo to capture the string? actually whenever it calls the getinfo it needs to return local string(strng).and that string to be stored in string variable.